# Ignoring a directory...but not a subdirectory or two

Tags: git, gitignore

I always thought I knew how to ignore and negate patterns, but I'm stumped. I have a baseline Drupal install and I'd like to ignore everything in the `sites/` folder except for a couple of specific subdirectories: `sites/all` and `sites/my-project`.

```
.vagrant
settings.php

# A directory set aside for user contributed assets
uploads/

# All we care about is sites/all and sites/my-project
www/sites/*
!www/sites/all
!www/sites/my-project
```

Given the above `.gitignore` file in the project root, when I do a `git add .`, I get everything I'd expect from `www/sites/all`, but nothing from `www/sites/my-project`. What am I missing here? There's only one file that I care about (`www/sites/my-project/settings.sample.php`) right now, but I can't figure out why it's not adding like everything else.

I know I could force it, but I want to understand the larger issue. What am I missing here? For whatever it's worth, this is my initial commit. I don't that it matters in any way, but I also don't know that it doesn't.

**UPDATE**

Whoops! Looks like the one file I care about *is* being ignored (which would explain why the directory is ignored). I have no idea where or why, but it gives me places to look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem:

```
$ find .
.
./.gitignore
./www
./www/sites
./www/sites/ignored
./www/sites/ignored/file
./www/sites/my-project
./www/sites/my-project/file
./www/sites/my-project/settings.sample.php
./www/sites/all
./www/sites/all/file
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/desert69/tmp/gitignore/.git/
$ cat .gitignore 
.vagrant
settings.php

# A directory set aside for user contributed assets
uploads/

# All we care about is sites/all and sites/my-project
www/sites/*
!www/sites/all
!www/sites/my-project
$ git add .
$ git status --short
A  .gitignore
A  www/sites/all/file
A  www/sites/my-project/file
A  www/sites/my-project/settings.sample.php
$ git --version
git version 1.7.10.4
```

So everything seems to be working.

Try doing a `rm -rf .git/ && git init` just in case you previously ignored or added any other file.

I thought maybe there was anything with the dot in `settings.php` being interpreted as an `*` so it matched `.sample.`, but don't seems to.

Try deleting and re-`init`ing the repository.

Comment: So it turns out that Drupal has it's own `.gitignore` that I didn't know about (I'm not a Drupal dev). Found it, opened it and saw `sites/*/settings*.php`. **le sigh

Comment: @RobWilkerson but, where's that `.gitignore`? How did you get the `.gitignore` you posted? Glad to see it worked, anyway :)