# Ignore all the files in the root except for some particular files, directories

Tags: git, gitignore

I supposed this to do the trick:

```
*
!/dir1/
!/dir2/
!/file1
!/file2
```

But to my surprise, it didn't. It seems to work if I prepend a slash before the asterisk. But I don't really understand why it doesn't work before this change. Could anybody point out?

Comment: see if this sheds any insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/whitelisting-and-subdirectories-in-git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use negating patterns `!` in `.gitignore`, just remember 2 rules.

**Rule 1. Files and directories are separatedly handled in the patterns. To include a directory back doesn't mean its child files/directories are also included back.**

I.E. The goal is to exclude all files/directories except everything inside `/dir1`. The following does NOT work.

```
# CANNOT work
*
!/dir1/
```

Why? The reason is just the first rule. Though the directory `dir1` is included again, but not all its child files/directories. And only including the directory without its children means nothing to git, since git won't track empty folders.

As a comparison, the following works.

```
# works
/*
!/dir1/
```

Why? Because `/*` only matches the files/directories under the root directory directly, but not ignores any files/directories under sub-directories such as `dir1` here. After `!/dir1/` includes `dir1` back, all its child files/directories are back naturely.

Someone may ask, if so, why the following doesn't work, since `!/dir1/**` will includes all child files/directories of `dir1` back?

```
# CANNOT work
*
!/dir1/**
```

The reason is in rule 2.

**Rule 2. It won't include files/directories back if their parent directory is still ignored.** For this rule, please read [my answer to a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25716803/2749114) first.

That's why the previous patterns won't work. And if we add another negating pattern to include the parent directory `dir1` back first, it works.

```
# works
*
!/dir1/
!/dir1/**
```

---

After understanding the 2 rules, the solutions for OP's case is quite straightforward.

The following works.

```
/*
!/dir1/
!/dir2/
!/file1
!/file2
```

And the following also works.

```
*
!/dir1/
!/dir1/**
!/dir2/
!/dir2/**
!/file1
!/file2
```

To make it simple as follows.

```
*
!*/
!/dir1/**
!/dir2/**
!/file1
!/file2
```

Comment: Great. The `/*` solution is the best among the options, in my opinion. Because it makes `git` reinclude the least amount of files.