# Git ignore unignore not working?

Tags: git, gitignore

I've looked at this answer: [Unignore subdirectories of ignored directories in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261959/unignore-subdirectories-of-ignored-directories-in-git)

And as far as I can tell I am doing the same thing, but git refuses to unignore my directories/files.

These are my rules. I'm trying to just get the listed directories/subdirectories, but the entire public directory is not showing up.

```
/public/bootstrap/*
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/*
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/**/*
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I just replicated this structure and `variables.less` was not ignored. Are you sure you don't have another `.gitignore` that might be catching it?

Comment: Did a find in the whole project folder, and the only other .gitignore is in a different directory and just has "local" in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it as follows. The sentence `"You can't unignore more than one level deep per line"` is not correct. You may refer to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26153424/2749114).

```
/public/bootstrap/**
!/public/bootstrap/**/
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/**
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less
```

Comment: So if I'm reading this right, the 1st line ignores all, the 2nd line unignores all directories, the 3rd line unignores all files and directories in dist? And, if I understand right, all the folders are now unignored, but since the files in the non-dist one are ignored, git won't do anything with them?

Answer (score 7):

After doing some reading and a LOT of trial and error, this works:

```
/public/bootstrap/bower_components/jquery
/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/**
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/**
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/less/
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less
```

The issue seems to be this line in the docs: "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded."

This seems to directly contradict other answers, but appears to be how it works for me.

In my testing I found if you ignore like this:

```
/public/bootstrap/*
```

You can't unignore more than one level deep per line.

```
# doesn't work
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/

# works
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/
!/public/bootstrap/bower_components/bootstrap/
```

Answer (score 3):

A command line that helps testing if you got it right: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore

The following CLI:

```
git check-ignore -v .idea/bbb.txt .idea/workspace.xml .idea/runConfigurations/Android_Debug___ReactNative.xml android/.idea/aaaa.txt android/.idea/runConfigurations/app.xml
```

Outputs the following:

```
.gitignore:33:**/.idea/**   .idea/bbb.txt
.gitignore:33:**/.idea/**   .idea/workspace.xml
.gitignore:35:!**/.idea/runConfigurations/* .idea/runConfigurations/Android_Debug___ReactNative.xml
.gitignore:33:**/.idea/**   android/.idea/aaaa.txt
.gitignore:35:!**/.idea/runConfigurations/* android/.idea/runConfigurations/app.xml
```

Pay attention that the 3rd and 5th lines are successfully un-ignored (watch for the "!" sign).

My .gitignore file:

```
**/.idea/**
!**/.idea/runConfigurations/
!**/.idea/runConfigurations/*
```