# Allowing files within folders in .gitignore not working

Tags: git, gitignore

Seen as my project is reaching half a gigabyte of disk space I'd like to avoid uploading/downloading that. But I do need to keep my project group up-to-date with all the changes that are being made by everyone on the team.

So when I tried to make a `.gitignore` to ignore everything except my C# files it ignored everything instead of committing them.

It works for the `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore`, though.
Which I find weird.

```
#Ignore everything
/*

#Except the neccesary files.
!.gitattributes
!.gitignore
!*.cs
!/Assets/RFPSP/
!/Assets/RFPSP/Scripts/*
!/Assets/RFPSP/Scripts/*/*
!/Assets/RFPSP/Scripts/*/*/*
```

I know the location of the code files (referenced above to the folder: "Scripts" and folders within that.) but it doesn't seem to work. If at all possible I'd like to keep the folder structure intact too, so that I can initialize a git repo on my main folder and update the file(s) in their respective location(s).

I thought this was the way to do it. Am I horribly mistaken or am I doing something terribly wrong?

Comment: try without initial backspace on directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following `.gitignore` configuration. It should work for your case. The first two lines make the trick.

```
/**
!/**/
!.gitattributes
!.gitignore
!*.cs
!Assets/RFPSP/Scripts/**
```

Refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26153424/2749114) here for explanations.

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wish to ignore folders you have to use `**` instead of `*`

```
!*.cs
!Assets/RFPSP/
!Assets/RFPSP/Scripts/**

# those are already matched in the above previous line so you wont need them
!Assets/RFPSP/Scripts/**/**
!Assets/RFPSP/Scripts/**/**/**
```

Comment: `https://github.com/sxbrentxs/FPS-GLU/blob/master/.gitignore` I tried that, but it doesn't want to work.